# Keep the last n columns of rows with variable length

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in Excel. Like this:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k | l |
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |  |  |  |  |

How can I get the last n columns of each row, like this (in this case, n=2)?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c | d |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| e | f |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| k | l |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| g | h |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I tried the following:

```vb
Sub keep_last_n_columns()

Dim selectedRange As Range
Dim numColumnsToKeep As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Integer

' Prompt user to select a range
On Error Resume Next
Set selectedRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if a range is selected
If selectedRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No range selected. Macro canceled.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Prompt user to enter the number of columns to keep
On Error Resume Next
numColumnsToKeep = Application.InputBox("Enter the number of columns to keep for each row:", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0

' Check if a valid number is entered
If numColumnsToKeep <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid number of columns. Macro canceled.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Loop through each row in the selected range
For i = 1 To selectedRange.Rows.Count
' Find the last column with data in the current row
lastColumn = selectedRange.Cells(i, selectedRange.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' Keep only the specified number of columns
If lastColumn > numColumnsToKeep Then
    selectedRange.Rows(i).Resize(, lastColumn - numColumnsToKeep).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It is keeping the last n rows of the biggest row and deleting the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is, that you are looking at the whole range of each row - which includes the empty cells as well.

This code counts the non-empty cells by using worksheet function `CountA` (assuming a continous range of values) and then resizes the row accordingly to get the cells for deletion:

```vb
Public Sub keepLastNColumns(rg As Range, n As Long)
Dim r As Range
Dim cntCells As Long, i As Long

For Each r In rg.Rows
    cntCells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(r)
    r.Resize(, cntCells - n).Delete xlShiftToLeft
Next

End Sub
```

You can call this sub like this:
`keepLastNColumns selectedRange, numColumnsToKeep`

Answer (score 0):

There is one slight problem with the code. The row which is the longest and the selection is just to the end of that row will be intact because of the End method which results the column 1 in this case. Therefore increment with one the starting cell column value sg. like this

```
lastColumn = selectedRange.Cells(i, selectedRange.Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
```